# How to split a string field in several rows in Oracle Data Integrator 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am a newbie in ODI 12c. I have recently installed it and had several tests on it. My problem is that I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to split **RULES** column in different rows like this in ODI 12c:

[image]

Would you please guide me how I can do that in ODI 12c?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I never worked with `ODI 12c` but are you lookin for a query ?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure, but maybe I can use the query in ODI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` cannot be directly used within ODI (*except can be used within a DB view*) while `REGEXP_REPLACE()` can be for version 12. But it would be easier to operate through use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function in order to split if it could be used. But the other function is harder to use for such splitting purposes.

Alternatively, you can  use standard former functions such as `SUBSTR()`, `INSTR()` and `LENGTH()` along with a Hierarchical Query in order to generate rows as per split such as :

```
 SELECT timestamp,
        CASE WHEN level = 1 
             THEN SUBSTR( rules, 1, INSTR(rules,',') - 1 )
             WHEN level = LENGTH(rules) - LENGTH(REPLACE(rules,',')) + 1
             THEN SUBSTR( rules, INSTR(rules,',',1,level-1)+1,
                                 LENGTH(rules)-INSTR(rules,',',1,level-1)+1)
             ELSE SUBSTR( rules, INSTR(rules,',',1,level-1)+1,  
                                 INSTR(rules,',',1,level)-INSTR(rules,',',1,level-1)-1)
              END AS rules
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(rules) - LENGTH(REPLACE(rules,',')) + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR timestamp = timestamp
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccf5d8b14015009298594fa776159716)</kbd>

Comment: Dear @Barbaros,thank you for your feedback. I used a query in toad, but it was so slow. I'll check this one and write the result here.

Comment: you're welcome @M_Gh . Btw, I assumed the rules strings don't contain any whitespaces, even not padded at the trailing or at the beginning, aren't they? For those having padded whitespeces at the end or beginning, the TRIM() function might also be added for rules column.

Comment: I don't know why I use this query in Creating a new table, it takes a lot of time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with ODI, but a query like the one below should split your rules so that each rule has its own line.

```
WITH
    some_data (timestamp, rules)
    AS
        (SELECT SYSDATE, '2,4,5' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SYSDATE - 1, '3,6' FROM DUAL)
  SELECT sd.timestamp,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR (sd.rules,
                        '[^,]+',
                        1,
                        lines.COLUMN_VALUE)    AS rule_number
    FROM some_data sd,
         TABLE (CAST (MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL     AS level_num
                                      FROM DUAL
                                CONNECT BY INSTR (sd.rules,
                                                  ',',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL - 1) > 0) AS SYS.odciNumberList)) lines
ORDER BY timestamp, rule_number;
```